# Prepend a string property value based on its parent array key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

Context: I want to be able to look through my nested arrays of objects and depending on the array key that property belonged to then prepend the string.

Issue: I was able to do it before I changed my data structure to include more objects within the parent array. Probably not the most efficient way to do it but it worked (appreciate any pointers on tidying this up).

*method to append:*

```
for (let key in temps) {
  let test = temps[key].display;
  if (key === "room1") {
    temps[key].display = "Our friend: " + test;
  }
  if (key === "room2") {
    temps[key].display = "Our friend: " + test;
  }
  if (key === "room3") {
    temps[key].display = "Unknown:" + test;
  }
}
```

So I am appending the value of `display` depending on the parent key they came from "room1, room2 or room3".

*Original data structure:*

```
let temps = {
  room1: { id: 1, display: "shahid" },
  room2: { id: 2, display: "akram" },
  room3: { id: 3, display: "zia" }
};
```

*New data structure:*

```
let temps = {
  room1: [{ id: 1, display: "shahid" }, { id: 11, display: "Zen" }],
  room2: [{ id: 2, display: "akram" }, { id: 12, display: "Julia" }],
  room3: [{ id: 3, display: "zia" }, { id: 13, display: "Octane" }]
};
```

So how do I get the method to work with my new data structure... better still, whats a better way of doing this if any please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your new structure has an extra (array) layer, you need an extra level of looping:

```js
let temps = {
  room1: [{ id: 1, display: "shahid" }, { id: 11, display: "Zen" }],
  room2: [{ id: 2, display: "akram" }, { id: 12, display: "Julia" }],
  room3: [{ id: 3, display: "zia" }, { id: 13, display: "Octane" }]
};

for (let key in temps) {
  for (let item of temps[key]) {
    let test = item.display;
    if (key === "room1") {
      item.display = "Our friend: " + test;
    }
    if (key === "room2") {
      item.display = "Our friend: " + test;
    }
    if (key === "room3") {
      item.display = "Unknown:" + test;
    }
  }
}

console.log(temps);
```

### Remarks

There are a few things you could improve. For instance, it is a pity that you *overwrite* the original display name, which really is a user name. The way it gets displayed should better be a *separate* property. Imagine that such a user-object would *move* to another room, and then updating that property...

If your rooms are really called `room1`, `room2`, ...etc, then using those as object keys is not really called for. Then you are better off with an array, where the index determines the room.

I would also suggest using more descriptive variable names. `temps` or `test` are not very descriptive of what they really represent. `rooms` and `name` would probably better describe what they are.

For instance:

```js
let rooms = [
  [{ id: 1, name: "shahid" }, { id: 11, name: "Zen" }],
  [{ id: 2, name: "akram" }, { id: 12, name: "Julia" }],
  [{ id: 3, name: "zia" }, { id: 13, name: "Octane" }]
];

for (let [roomId, room] of rooms.entries()) {
  for (let item of room) {
    item.display = (roomId === 2 ? "Unknown: " : "Our friend: ") + item.name;
  }
}

console.log(rooms);
```

Or in an object oriented way, where you can define methods to move users in and out of a room, and where the display feature can determine the string dynamically on-the-fly (as a getter):

```js
class User {
    constructor(id, name) { 
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.room = null;
    }
    exitRoom() {
        if (this.room) this.room.removeUser(this);
    }
    enterRoom(room) {
        room.addUser(room);
    }
    get display() {
        return (this.room?.hasFriends ? "Our friend: " : "Unknown: ") + this.name;
    }
}

class Room {
    constructor(name, hasFriends=false) {
        this.name = name;
        this.users = [];
        this.hasFriends = hasFriends;
    }
    addUser(user) {
        if (user.room) user.room.removeUser(user);
        user.room = this;
        this.users.push(user);
        return this;
    }
    removeUser(user) {
        if (user.room != this) return;
        this.users.splice(this.users.indexOf(user), 1);
        user.room = null;
    }
}

let rooms = [
    new Room("room1", true)
        .addUser(new User(1, "shahid"))
        .addUser(new User(11, "Zen")),
    new Room("room2", true)
        .addUser(new User(2, "akram"))
        .addUser(new User(12, "Julia")),
    new Room("room3", false)
        .addUser(new User(3, "zia"))
        .addUser(new User(13, "Octane")),
];

for (let room of rooms) {
  console.log(`Room: ${room.name}`);
  for (let user of room.users) {
    console.log(`  ${user.display}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer thanks. Yes the variable names was just for demo - i would never use variable names like that. I do have another prop for the username, so I will only overwrite the display name. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```js
let temps = {
  room1: [{ id: 1, display: "shahid" }, { id: 11, display: "Zen" }],
  room2: [{ id: 2, display: "akram" }, { id: 12, display: "Julia" }],
  room3: [{ id: 3, display: "zia" }, { id: 13, display: "Octane" }]
};


temps = Object.keys(temps).map(function (key) {
   return { [key]: temps[key] };
});


for (let i of temps) {
  for (let key in i) {
  
  if (key === "room1") {
    i[key].forEach(e=>e.display = "Our friend: "+e.display);
  }
  if (key === "room2") {
   i[key].forEach(e=>e.display = "Our friend: "+e.display );
  }
  if (key === "room3") {
  i[key].forEach(e=>e.display = "Unknown: "+e.display );
  }
}

}

console.log(temps)
```